# Check If Image Is Colored Or Not

Tags: c#, .net, image, gdi+, pixelformat

I'm trying to figure out whether an image is colored or not. On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150504/how-can-i-check-the-color-depth-of-a-bitmap) StackOverflow question, there's a reply that says that I should check the `PixelFormat` enum of the `Image`. Unfortunately, the reply isn't very clear to me. Is it safe to check whether the `image.PixelFormat` is different from `PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale` to consider that it is a colored image? What about the other values of the enumeration? The MSDN documentation isn't very clear...

Comment: Would you like to check if it supports colors, or if it contains colors? It can be Format32bppArgb and still contain only black, white and gray.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: I want to know whether it contains colors.

Comment: That's a different thing, then. Do you want it to work for every PixelFormat?

Comment: @YoryeNathan: I'm not really sure to be honest. The thing is that the user can upload an image to the site, then I need to check whether this image is colored or not. Accordingly, I need to do different things...

Comment: The user uploads an image of any type, then? There's a file dialog box, etc? No extension filter?

Comment: There is a GetPixel method on Bitmap. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx you could then check the RGB values of every pixel but that kind of sucks.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: No, I will restrict it to jpg, png and gif images.

Comment: @AndrewJones: Yeh well this is what I'm trying to avoid...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can improve this by avoiding Color.FromArgb, and iterating over bytes instead of ints, but I thought this would be more readable for you, and easier to understand as an approach.

The general idea is draw the image into a bitmap of known format (32bpp ARGB),
and then check whether that bitmap contains any colors.

Locking the bitmap's bits allows you to iterate through it's color-data many times faster than using GetPixel, using unsafe code.

If a pixel's alpha is 0, then it is obviously GrayScale, because alpha 0 means it's completely opaque. Other than that - if R = G = B, then it is gray (and if they = 255, it is black).

```
private static unsafe bool IsGrayScale(Image image)
{
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
    {
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
        }

        var data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

        var pt = (int*)data.Scan0;
        var res = true;

        for (var i = 0; i < data.Height * data.Width; i++)
        {
            var color = Color.FromArgb(pt[i]);

            if (color.A != 0 && (color.R != color.G || color.G != color.B))
            {
                res = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        bmp.UnlockBits(data);

        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad I helped. Just make sure I didn't confuse with the alpha (0 or 255). Other than that it should go smooth :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    private bool isGrayScale(Bitmap processedBitmap)
    { 
        bool res = true;
        unsafe
        {
            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bitmapData = processedBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, processedBitmap.Width, processedBitmap.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, processedBitmap.PixelFormat);
            int bytesPerPixel = System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(processedBitmap.PixelFormat) / 8;
            int heightInPixels = bitmapData.Height;
            int widthInBytes = bitmapData.Width * bytesPerPixel;
            byte* PtrFirstPixel = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;
            Parallel.For(0, heightInPixels, y =>
            {
                byte* currentLine = PtrFirstPixel + (y * bitmapData.Stride);
                for (int x = 0; x < widthInBytes; x = x + bytesPerPixel)
                {
                    int b = currentLine[x];
                    int g = currentLine[x + 1];
                    int r = currentLine[x + 2];
                    if (b != g || r != g)
                    {
                        res = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
            processedBitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Please add some context to your answer and explain what the code does. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

SimpleVar's answer is *mostly* correct: that code doesn't properly handle when the source image has an indexed color format.

To solve this, simply replace the outer `using` block with:

```cs
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(image)) {
```

and remove the inner `using` entirely, as the `Graphics` object is no longer needed. This will create a perfect copy of the image in a non-indexed format, regardless of the original image's pixel format.