# How to check if a picture is in grayScale

Tags: c#, bitmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check the color depth of a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150504/how-can-i-check-the-color-depth-of-a-bitmap)

I'm receiving the path of a picture. I would need to know if that picture is in grayScale. How can I do this?

I'm trying to load that path to a Bitmap using this code, but it keeps saying me that the parameter is not valid.

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(pFilePath);
```

Can I check if it is in grayScale from a ByteArray? Or is there some way to do it from a Bitmap? How would that be?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that file is really in the path you're passing? Try `Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(pFilePath);`

Comment: Here is your answer : [Check if a picture is in grayscale][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150504/how-can-i-check-the-color-depth-of-a-bitmap

Comment: The problem is that I've tried to create a Bitmap from that path, but it throws me an error.

Answer (score 0):

check this [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.pixelformat.aspx)

```
image.PixelFormat
```

It will match one of the values in [System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx)

Comment: I think it will have `PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale`

Comment: This solution is wrong because the expected PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale will not be returned for grayscale images in 32bpp, here more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374760/how-to-find-that-all-pixels-in-an-image-are-grey-scale-or-has-r-g-b-equal-value