# Analyze colors of an Image

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, graphics, gdi+

I have part of an Image cropped out, and 2 Color Ranges (H/S/L) defined via 12 trackbars. I also have a "Precision/Speed" slider ranging from 1 to 10.

I need to analyze how many pixels of the Image fall into each of the specified Color Ranges.
Based on the precision/speed slider, I skip some rows/pixels.

Its working great but its too slow. With high precision (trackbar value = 1), it takes about 550 ms.
With low precision but high speed (trackbar value = 10) it takes about 5 ms.

Is there a way to speed this code up? Ideally I would need it to be 5 times faster.

```
 For y As Integer = 0 To 395
    If y Mod 2 = 0 Then
        startpixel = tbval / 2
    Else
        startpixel = 0
    End If

    If y Mod tbval = 0 Then
        For x As Integer = 0 To 1370
            If x Mod tbval - startpixel = 0 Then
                analyzedpixels = analyzedpixels + 1

                Dim pColor As Color = crop.GetPixel(x, y)
                Dim h As Integer = pColor.GetHue
                Dim s As Integer = pColor.GetSaturation * 100
                Dim l As Integer = pColor.GetBrightness * 100

                'verify if it is part of the first color

                If h >= h1min And h <= h1max And s >= s1min And s <= s1max And l >= l1min And l <= l1max Then
                    color1pixels = color1pixels + 1
                End If

                If h >= h2min And h <= h2max And s >= s2min And s <= s2max And l >= l2min And l <= l2max Then
                    color2pixels = color2pixels + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

---

EDIT:

This is the working code..

```
Dim rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, crop.Width, crop.Height)
Dim bdata As Imaging.BitmapData = crop.LockBits(rect, Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, crop.PixelFormat)

Dim ptr As IntPtr = bdata.Scan0
Dim bytes As Integer = Math.Abs(bdata.Stride) * crop.Height
Dim rgbValues As Byte() = New Byte(bytes - 1) {}
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes)

For i As Integer = 0 To crop.Height - 1

    If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
        startpixel = tbval / 2
    Else
        startpixel = 0
    End If

    If i Mod tbval = 0 Then
        For j As Integer = 0 To crop.Width - 1
            If j Mod tbval - startpixel = 0 Then

                analyzedpixels = analyzedpixels + 1
                Dim position = (bdata.Stride * i) + j * 4
                Dim c = Color.FromArgb(BitConverter.ToInt32(rgbValues, position))
                Dim h As Integer = c.GetHue
                Dim s As Integer = c.GetSaturation * 100
                Dim l As Integer = c.GetBrightness * 100

                If h >= h1min And h <= h1max And s >= s1min And s <= s1max And l >= l1min And l <= l1max Then
                    color1pixels = color1pixels + 1
                End If

                If h >= h2min And h <= h2max And s >= s2min And s <= s2max And l >= l2min And l <= l2max Then
                    color2pixels = color2pixels + 1
                End If
            End If
            stride += 4
        Next
    End If
Next

crop.UnlockBits(bdata)
```

Comment: @sharkyenergy You should use `AndAlso` instead of `And` because it can be faster: [What is the difference between And and AndAlso in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/302047/1115360)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When performing sequential operations on a Bitmap's color data, the [Bitmap.LockBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits) method can provide a huge increase in performace, since the Bitmap data needs to be loaded in memory just once, as opposed to sequential GetPixel/SetPixel calls: each call will load a partial section of the Bitmap data in memory and then discard it, to repeat the process when these methods are called again.

If a single call to GetPixel/SetPixel is needed instead, these methods may have a performace advantage over `Bitmap.LockBits()`. But, in this case, performace is not a factor, in practice.

**How `Bitmap.LockBits()` works**:

This is the function call:

```
public BitmapData LockBits (Rectangle rect, ImageLockMode flags, PixelFormat format);
// VB.Net
Public LockBits (rect As Rectangle, flags As ImageLockMode, format As PixelFormat) As BitmapData
```

- **`rect As Rectangle`**: This parameter specifies the section of the Bitmap data we're interested in; this section's bytes will be loaded in memory. It can be the whole size of the Bitmap or a smaller section of it.
- **`flags As`** [`ImageLockMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imagelockmode):  Specifies the type of lock to perform. The access to the memory to can be limited to Read or Write, or concurrent Read/Write operations are allowed.
  It can be also used to specify - setting **`ImageLockMode.UserInputBuffer`** - that the [BitmapData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata) object is provided by the calling code.
  The **`BitmapData`** object defines some of the Bitmap properties (`Width` and `Height` of the Bitmap, width of the scan line (the **`Stride`**: number of bytes that compose a single line of pixels, represented by the `Bitmap.Width` multiplied by the number of bytes per pixel, rounded to a 4-bytes boundary. See the note about the `Stride`).
  The [BitmapData.Scan0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.scan0) property is the Pointer (`IntPtr`) to the initial memory location where the Bitmap data is stored.
  This property allows to specify the memory location where a pre-existing Bitmap data buffer is already stored. It becomes useful when Bitmap data is exchanged between processes using Pointers.
  Note that the MSDN documentation about `ImageLockMode.UserInputBuffer` is confusing (if not wrong).
- **`format As`** [`PixelFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.pixelformat): the format used to describe the Color of a single Pixel. It translates, in practice, in the number of bytes used to represent a Color.
  When `PixelFormat = Format24bppRgb`, each Color is represented by 3 bytes (RGB values). With `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`, each Color is represented by 4 bytes (RGB values + Alpha).
  Indexed formats, as `Format8bppIndexed`, specify that each byte value is the index to a [Palette](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.colorpalette) entry. The `Palette` is part of the Bitmap information, except when the pixel format is `PixelFormat.Indexed`: in this case, each value is an entry in the System color table.
  The default `PixelFormat` of a new Bitmap object, if not specified, is `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`, or `PixelFormat.Canonical`.

**Important notes about the Stride:**

As mentioned before, the **`Stride`** (also called scan-line) represents the number of bytes that compose a single line of pixels. Because of harware alignment requirements, it's always rounded up to a 4-bytes boundary (an integer number multiple of 4).

```
Stride =  [Bitmap Width] * [bytes per Color]
Stride += (Stride Mod 4) * [bytes per Color]
```

This is one of the reasons why we always work with Bitmaps created with `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`: the Bitmap's `Stride` is always already aligned to the required boundary.

*What if the Bitmap's format is instead* **`PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb`** *(3 bytes per Color)*?

If the Bitmap's `Width` multiplied by the Bytes per Pixels is not a multiple of `4`, the `Stride` will be padded with `0`s to fill the gap.

A Bitmap of size `(100 x 100)` will have no padding in both 32 bit and 24 bit formats:

```
100 * 3 = 300 : 300 Mod 4 = 0 : Stride = 300
100 * 4 = 400 : 400 Mod 4 = 0 : Stride = 400
```

It will be different for a Bitmap of size `(99 x 100)`:

```
99 * 3 = 297 : 297 Mod 4 = 1 : Stride = 297 + ((297 Mod 4) * 3) = 300
99 * 4 = 396 : 396 Mod 4 = 0 : Stride = 396
```

The `Stride` of a 24 bit Bitmap is padded adding 3 bytes (set to `0`) to fill the boundary.

It's not a *problem* when we inspect/modify internal values accessing single Pixels by their coordinates, similar to how SetPixel/GetPixel operate: the position of a Pixel will always be found correctly.

Suppose we need to inspect/change a Pixel at position `(98, 70)` in a Bitmap of size `(99 x 100)`.
Considering only the bytes per pixel. The pixel position inside the Buffer is:

```
[Bitmap] = new Bitmap(99, 100, PixelFormat = Format24bppRgb)

[Bytes x pixel] = Image.GetPixelFormatSize([Bitmap].PixelFormat) / 8
[Pixel] = new Point(98, 70)
[Pixel Position] = ([Pixel].Y * [BitmapData.Stride]) + ([Pixel].X * [Bytes x pixel])
[Color] = Color.FromArgb([Pixel Position] + 2, [Pixel Position] + 1, [Pixel Position])
```

Multiplying the Pixel's *vertical* position by the width of the scan line, the position inside the buffer will always be correct: the padded size is included in the calculation.
The Pixel Color at the next position, `(0, 71)`, will return the expected results:

It will be different when reading color bytes sequentially.
The first scan line will return valid results up to the last Pixel (the last 3 bytes): the next 3 bytes will return the value of the bytes used to round the `Stride`, all set to `0`.

This might also not be a problem. For example, applying a filter, each sequence of bytes that represent a pixel is read and modifyed using the values of the filter's matrix: we would just modify a sequence of 3 bytes that won't be considered when the Bitmap is rendered.

But it does matter if we are searching for specific sequences of pixels: reading a non-existent pixel Color may compromise the result and/or unbalance an algorithm.
The same when performing statistical analisys on a Bitmap's colors.

Of course, we could add a check in the loop: `if [Position] Mod [BitmapData].Width = 0 : continue`.
But this adds a new calculation to each iteration.

**Operations in practice**

The simple solution (the more common one) is to create a new Bitmap with a format of `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`, so the `Stride` will be always correctly aligned:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Private Function CopyTo32BitArgb(image As Image) As Bitmap
    Dim imageCopy As New Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    imageCopy.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution)

    For Each propItem As PropertyItem In image.PropertyItems
        imageCopy.SetPropertyItem(propItem)
    Next

    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imageCopy)
        g.DrawImage(image,
            New Rectangle(0, 0, imageCopy.Width, imageCopy.Height),
            New Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height),
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        g.Flush()
    End Using
    Return imageCopy
End Function
```

This generates a byte-compatible Bitmap with the same DPI definition; the [Image.PropertyItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.propertyitems) are also copied from the source image.

To test it, let's apply a sepia tone filter to an Image, using a copy of it to perform all the modifications needed to the Bitmap data:

```
Public Function BitmapFilterSepia(source As Image) As Bitmap
    Dim imageCopy As Bitmap = CopyTo32BitArgb(source)
    Dim imageData As BitmapData = imageCopy.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height),
        ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(Math.Abs(imageData.Stride) * imageCopy.Height - 1) {}
    Marshal.Copy(imageData.Scan0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

    Dim bytesPerPixel = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(source.PixelFormat) \ 8;
    Dim red As Single = 0, green As Single = 0, blue As Single = 0

    Dim pos As Integer = 0
    While pos < buffer.Length
        Dim color As Color = Color.FromArgb(BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, pos))
        ' Dim h = color.GetHue()
        ' Dim s = color.GetSaturation()
        ' Dim l = color.GetBrightness()

        red = buffer(pos) * 0.189F + buffer(pos + 1) * 0.769F + buffer(pos + 2) * 0.393F
        green = buffer(pos) * 0.168F + buffer(pos + 1) * 0.686F + buffer(pos + 2) * 0.349F
        blue = buffer(pos) * 0.131F + buffer(pos + 1) * 0.534F + buffer(pos + 2) * 0.272F

        buffer(pos + 2) = CType(Math.Min(Byte.MaxValue, red), Byte)
        buffer(pos + 1) = CType(Math.Min(Byte.MaxValue, green), Byte)
        buffer(pos) = CType(Math.Min(Byte.MaxValue, blue), Byte)
        pos += bytesPerPixel
    End While

    Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, imageData.Scan0, buffer.Length)
    imageCopy.UnlockBits(imageData)
    imageData = Nothing
    Return imageCopy
End Function
```

`Bitmap.LockBits` is not always necessarily the *best* choice available.
The same procedure to apply a filter could also be performed quite easily using the [ColorMatrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix) class, which allows to apply a `5x5` matrix transformation to a Bitmap, using just a simple array of float (`Single`) values.

For example, let's apply a Grayscale filter using the `ColorMatrix` class and a well-known `5x5` Matrix:

```
Public Function BitmapMatrixFilterGreyscale(source As Image) As Bitmap
    ' A copy of the original is not needed but maybe desirable anyway 
    ' Dim imageCopy As Bitmap = CopyTo32BitArgb(source)
    Dim filteredImage = New Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height, source.PixelFormat)
    filteredImage.SetResolution(source.HorizontalResolution, source.VerticalResolution)

    Dim grayscaleMatrix As New ColorMatrix(New Single()() {
        New Single() {0.2126F, 0.2126F, 0.2126F, 0, 0},
        New Single() {0.7152F, 0.7152F, 0.7152F, 0, 0},
        New Single() {0.0722F, 0.0722F, 0.0722F, 0, 0},
        New Single() {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        New Single() {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
   })

    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(filteredImage), attributes = New ImageAttributes()
        attributes.SetColorMatrix(grayscaleMatrix)
        g.DrawImage(source, New Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height),
                    0, 0, source.Width, source.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes)
    End Using
    Return filteredImage
End Function
```

Comment: "bytes per color" only works as long as you don't go under 8 bit per pixel formats, though. A more universal stride calculation is `(((((bitsPerPixel * width) + 7) / 8) + 3) / 4) * 4`

Comment: @Nyerguds These notes are quite explicitly related to 24 and 32 bit images (with a quite explicit suggestion to use the latter alone). Indexed colors are not addressed, nor formats such as 16 bit Grayscale and similar. About these, I've posted s sample class to analyze them here: [How to determine if an Image is Grayscale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481035/7444103). Btw, if you give it a look and you have some *notes* about it, don't refrain from commenting, I like your comments :)