# Resizing a Bitmap manually

Tags: c#, bitmap, scaling, image-scaling, bitmapdata

We are using a camera that acquires up to 60 frames per second, providing Bitmaps for us to use in our codebase.

As our wpf-app requires, these bitmaps are scaled based on a scaling factor; That scaling-process is by far the most limiting factor when it comes to actually displaying 60 fps. I am aware of `new Bitmap(Bitmap source, int width, int height)` which is obviously the simplest way to resize a Bitmap;

Nevertheless, I am trying to implement a "manual" approach using BitmapData and pointers. I have come up with the following:

```
public static Bitmap /*myMoBetta*/ResizeBitmap(this Bitmap bmp, double scaleFactor)
        {
            int desiredWidth = (int)(bmp.Width * scaleFactor),
                desiredHeight = (int)(bmp.Height * scaleFactor);

            var scaled = new Bitmap(desiredWidth, desiredHeight, bmp.PixelFormat);

            int formatSize = (int)Math.Ceiling(Image.GetPixelFormatSize(bmp.PixelFormat)/8.0);

            BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
            BitmapData scaledData = scaled.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, scaled.Width, scaled.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, scaled.PixelFormat);

            unsafe
            {
                var srcPtr = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0.ToPointer();
                var destPtr = (byte*)scaledData.Scan0.ToPointer();

                int scaledDataSize = scaledData.Stride * scaledData.Height;
                int nextPixel = (int)(1 / scaleFactor)*formatSize;

                Parallel.For(0, scaledDataSize - formatSize,
                    i =>
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < formatSize; j++)
                        {
                            destPtr[i + j] = srcPtr[i * nextPixel + j];
                        }
                    });
            }

            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
            bmp.Dispose();
            scaled.UnlockBits(scaledData);

            return scaled;
        }
```

Given scalingFactor < 1.
Actually using this algorithm does not seem to work, though. How are the bits of each pixel arranged in memory, exactly? My guess was that calling `Image.GetPixelFormatSize()` and deviding its result by 8 returns the number of bytes per pixel; But continuing to copy only `formatSize` amout of bytes every  `1 / scaleFactor * formatSize` byte results in a corrupted image.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you haven't noticed, but when your original Bitmap's `PixelFormat` is, e.g., `Format24bppRgb` and you create a new one with, e.g., `var resized = new Bitmap(original, 100, 100)`, the new Image `PixelFormat` is now `Format32bppArgb`.  Why is that? -- Read the *Important notes about the Stride* here: [Analyze colors of an Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59102380/7444103). -- Since you have a WPF app, why are you using GDI+ to scale bitmaps?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=stack+overflow+c%23+resize+image

Comment: @Jimi very insightful, I actually think that the padding with zeroes is an issue in this case. Regarding GDI+, `new Bitmap(original, width, height)` calls graphics.drawimage which in turn calls gdi+ externally. (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Bitmap.cs,324 | https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Graphics.cs,2841)

Comment: @OlivierRogier most answers to be found online just refer to GDI+

Comment: Padding is required because of hardware *alignment* (always 4-bytes aligned).  -- I was asking why do you use GDI+ when you have a WPF app. Other tools are used in this platform), GDI+ is common in WinForms (since its Controls can use Bitmap object, WPF's cannot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I bumped into OpenCV that has it's own .NET implementation with Emgu.CV, containing relevant methods for faster resizing.

My `ResizeBitmap()`-function has shrinked significantly:

```
public static Bitmap ResizeBitmap(this Bitmap bmp, int width, int height)
    {
        var desiredSize = new Size(width, height);
        var src = new Emgu.CV.Image<Rgb, byte>(bmp);
        var dest = new Emgu.CV.Image<Rgb, byte>(desiredSize);

        Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.Resize(src, dest, desiredSize);

        bmp.Dispose();
        src.Dispose();

        return dest.ToBitmap();
    }
```

I have not tested performance thouroughly, but while debugging, this implementation reduced executiontime from 22ms with `new Bitmap(source, width, height)` to about 7ms.