# How can I convert this code using GDI Bitmap pointers from C# to VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, pointers, translate, unsafe

I need help to convert my code from C# to VB.NET. I'm stuck on these lines:

```csharp
byte* ptr = (byte*)(void*)bitmapData.Scan0;
byte* ptr2 = (byte*)(void*)bitmapData2.Scan0;
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/raw/ddLDzSeK) is my full code.

Comment: If there is a legitimate need for pointers, this code can't be converted directly to VB.  There aren't many things that are impossible in VB, but true pointers in unsafe code are one area that can't be done.

Comment: You don't need pointers to access the Bitmap Data Bytes. You can use `Marshal.Copy()` to copy the unmanaged data to a managed buffer. VB.Net example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59102380/7444103)